# Issue with subnet when associating public IP address (non EIP) on a EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

In my setup, I would like to do the following:

1. create ENI with 'AssociatePublicIpAddress: True' in a non-default VPC and subnet (I also provide the subnet and sec group)
2. Create an instance
3. Attach the ENI to the instance

Expected result: Instance on the correct VPC, subnet and sec group.

I am able to successfully bring up the instance and attach the ENI. The public IP address (non-EIP) also is onboarded properly. However, the ENI is attached the a different VPC (the default VPC) with a different CIDR and subnet. As such, I cannot communicate with this instance via the local subnet and desired IP range.

I was wondering if anyone has run into this scenario and resolved it.

- Default VPC: 172.31.0.0/16
- Desired VPC: 11.11.0.0/16, subnet on 11.11.1.0/24
- Actual Instance IP is in the 172.31.0.0/16 subnet instead of the 11.11.1.0/24 subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the ENI with a subnet in that VPC.

> When you create a network interface, it inherits the public IPv4 addressing attribute from the subnet. If you later modify the public IPv4 addressing attribute of the subnet, the network interface keeps the setting that was in effect when it was created. If you launch an instance and specify an existing network interface for eth0, the public IPv4 addressing attribute is determined by the network interface.
>
> For more information, see Public IPv4 Addresses and External DNS Hostnames.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html

Comment: Thanks. Indeed, due to a bug, when I provided the network_interface list to the instance, the subnet information was missing. That is the reason EC2 was picking up the default subnet.